# renderincontext Memory Leak if not use on Main thread

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage, core-graphics

I am trying to convert my UIView into UIImage using below code.

```
+ (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view{
     float scale = 1.0f;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, YES, scale);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage* img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    view.layer.contents = nil;
    return img;
}
```

There are two problem with this code.

**1. When I run this code in background thread(!mainThread)**

I faced memory leak problem when renderInContext is called in background thread.

**2. When I run this code on Main thread**

There is no memory leak but on iPad 3 I am facing some performance issue (my UI hangs when this method is called) while creating image from UIView. As I need to call this function more than 5 times in a seconds so UI hangs gives very bad user experience.

Please guide me if I am doing some thing wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that issue 1 is related to the fact that `UIKit` is not thread safe and its use will lead to all kinds of side effects.

If you have performance issue like you are describing, the only path forward I see is directly using CoreGraphics (not UIKit) on a secondary thread.

You might try something like this, as a start:

```
size_t width = view.bounds.size.width;
size_t height = view.bounds.size.height;

unsigned char *imageBuffer = (unsigned char *)malloc(width*height*4);
CGColorSpaceRef colourSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

CGContextRef imageContext =
    CGBitmapContextCreate(imageBuffer, width, height, 8, width*4, colourSpace,
              kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little);

CGColorSpaceRelease(colourSpace);

[view.layer renderInContext:imageContext];

CGImageRef outputImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(imageContext);

CGImageRelease(outputImage);
CGContextRelease(imageContext);
free(imageBuffer);
```

As you see, this is pretty more complex than the `UIKit` way, but it can be run on a secondary thread (provided you find a way to pass the `outputImage` back to your UI thread which is not shown).

Comment: Have you seen my sample code? `outputImage` is a CGImageRef which you can use to create a `UIImage` through `imageWithCGImage:` -- but you should do this last step on the main thread...

Comment: I think, there is confusion, I want to convert UIView to UIImage.

Comment: ouch... you are right... please, see my edited code. this should do it.

Comment: I didn't know this is how you start a image context, cool stuff! However, post iOS 4, UIGraphicsBeginImageContext, et al., are all thread safe and not limited to the main thread anymore. See the notes: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#jumpTo_37

Comment: Great! I noticed that created image is flipped vertically.

Comment: To flip the image back to normal add these 2 lines after the CGColorSpaceRelease:      `CGContextTranslateCTM(imageContext, 0, height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(imageContext, 1.0f, -1.0f);`

Answer (score 2):

I just had this happen to me (memory leak due to `renderInContext`) on the *main* thread. I was looping over hundreds off-screen views, rendering them to `UIImage` objects, and saving them as PNG files. What solved the problem for me was wrapping the guts of my loop in an `@autoreleasepool` block:

**Broken:**

```
for (...) {
   ...render layer in context...
   ...save image to disk...
}
```

**Works:**

```
for (...) {
   @autoreleasepool {
      ...render layer in context...
      ...save image to disk...
   }
}
```

Makes sense, right?